# Jquery UI dialog, remove scrollbar if bootstrap columns are used

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4rbopvr/1/) to show my problem.

Isn't it possible to use bootstrap columns in a jquery ui dialog without getting this annoying horizontal scrollbar?

```html
Soory, I don't know how to insert the fiddle code with the right depencies in the right way.
```

Answer (score 0):

First think then write...

Just remove the "row" div and it works.

[Look here.](https://jsfiddle.net/rbrbhd4c/)

```html
Soory, I don't know how to insert the fiddle code with the right depencies in the right way.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "style='overflow-x:hidden;'" to the dialog container div.

```
function CreateBusinessDialog(action, formId) {
var contId = 'dlgcont_' + GetUidString();
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('id', contId);
container.setAttribute('style', 'overflow-x:hidden;');
document.body.appendChild(container);

$('#' + contId).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Create New',
    width: '75%', //$(window).width() - 150,
    height: $(window).height() - 150,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).load(action);
    },
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Create',
        click: function () {
            var form = $('#' + formId);
            form.validate();
            if (form.valid()) {
                //alert('valid');
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Close',
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }],
    close: function () {
        container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
    }
});

$('#' + contId).dialog('open');
```

}